# How can I disable kitty's paste from escaping?

Tags: zsh, escape-characters, oh-my-zsh, kitty

If I have the string and copy that with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
https://test.invalid/?foo=bar()&baz=$quz{}
```

And I paste that into the terminal I see the following,

```
https://test.invalid/\?foo\=bar\(\)\&baz\=$quz\{\}
```

However, I don't want the `?`, `(`, `)`,  `{`, `}`, and `=` escaped, as I'm using the paste string to fill out curl,

> `curl "`<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>`"`

How can I disable this character escaping behavior?

Comment: @jsotola take a look at that example, notice the `$` is not shell-escaped. Moreover even if it was the question would be valid, what if I want to paste it into vim for a script?

Comment: possibly `allow_hyperlinks no` setting in kitty.conf

Comment: But I want that, it's for launching a link in a browser not escaping links pasted (afaik). https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf.html?highlight=allow_hyperlink#opt-kitty.allow_hyperlinks

Comment: @jsotola self-answered below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't kitty. If you run `/bin/sh` and paste you can test that. The problem, in my case, was actually zsh. And specifically oh-my-zsh which has this in the `~/.zshrc` conf,

```
# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true
```

Uncommenting that fixed my problem.

- https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5499 original issue, but still broken for me with massively newer stuff.